# how to create dynamic items in liferay theme as per the values in the portlet

Tags: liferay, velocity, liferay-theme

I have a theme in liferay where there are some items in the side menu, I want to add some more items to the menu dynamically based on the values i obtained in the portlet's controller.

My theme is like this :

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="link" style="height: 609px;">    
        <li><a href="$themeDisplay.getPortalURL()/x" id="x" class="active">My Account<i class="pull-right" ></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="$themeDisplay.getPortalURL()/y" id="y" class="active">Settings<i class="pull-right" ></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a portlet from where I gets some values in a list

```
List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("test1");
renderRequest.setAttribute("list", list);
```

The list could have different values.

What I want is if I have a parameter called test1 in the list , I want to add a new parameter in the theme to be available for that particular user.

```
<li><a href="$themeDisplay.getPortalURL()/z" id="z" class="active">Bonus<i class="pull-right" ></i></a></li>
```

If it was JSP, I would have used the  but how can it be done in the liferay theme.(I am using velocity theme).

Comment: better solution is create 1 portlet with dynamic values & Embed that in theme

Comment: Could you please provide a more detail on how can this be done.

Comment: you create one portlet whose sole functionality is to display the dynamic items based on whatever logic u need .!
And then you embed it in your theme ..

Comment: The theme i am using should show a extra tab for that portlet , how can that be accomplished with it?

Comment: create one tab in theme & in tab content embed that portlet, can u post some screenshots, then i can tell exact code

Comment: actually its opposite that i require, I want to show a tab based on the value in the portlet.

Comment: ok,
tell me by default do you need to show any tab ?
i.e for the very first time, what should be the condition

Comment: by default the theme should have these tabs <ul class="link" style="height: 609px;">    
        <li><a href="$themeDisplay.getPortalURL()/x" id="x" class="active">My Account<i class="pull-right" ></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="$themeDisplay.getPortalURL()/y" id="y" class="active">Settings<i class="pull-right" ></i></a></li>
    </ul>

I have mentioned that in the post also.

the condition that i needed to check is a parameter in the list named test1

Comment: so create 1 portlet with this default content & embed this in theme,. .. now based on your conditions when u visit something manipulate the portlet.

Comment: Embedding portlet should be the last option on the list considering 1)Overhead of page load 2)Binding portlet to page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Olaf's reply,you should probably proceed with a better approach to this design.You can however use attributes from Servlet context in theme.
In your portlet class:

```
    HttpServletRequest request=PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(req);
    ServletContext servletContext=request.getSession().getServletContext();
    servletContext.setAttribute("param", "Product3");
```

which can then be retrieved in theme via request variable available in theme velocity template:

```
    $request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("param")
```

Comment: Thanks Shivam, Yes this is currently working for me , but the downside is if I have more than one portlet in the page , I have to place this code in all of the portlet for the theme to find the value I sets in the param.

Comment: It seems I am still not clear with the design,are you going to get params from all/multiple portlets on page, as the question mentions "I have a portlet"

Comment: Actually your answer worked for me , I was just considering a case as per which if I had more than one portlet in the page , then the same thing would not have worked.Thanks a Lot !!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

There's quite some discussion on this already in the comments to your question. Your theme can't access "your portlet's controller", it's the wrong way to think about the problem: If a portlet determines what to show, you should embed the portlet in the theme. After all, you probably want to interact with it, and that's the easiest way to do so.

*Even if* a portlet is present on a page, a theme can't arbitrarily use any portlet's request attributes - they're well shielded from accessing each other by design: Otherwise you'd have all kinds of conflicts between rogue portlets and themes.

And as long as you can't guarantee that a portlet is on the page, you can't just call arbitrary methods on the portlet anyways. (not that you could otherwise).

If you want to go through with implementing this functionality in a theme, say goodbye to "the portlet controller". You should have your code in an independent utility class, as a portlet in this case is just the wrong place for the implementation.

I'm not fully understanding your complete usecase, so I can't tell you which implementation makes most sense. Only that the combination you outline in your question makes the least sense to me.

Comment: @Navankur Adding on to Olaf's answere,are you looking to modify theme on the basis of user interaction(for which ur currently using portlet) or what exactly is the significance of the same?

Comment: yes @ShivamAggarwal , I have a page where there is a portlet and i have applied a theme in it , now as per the user interaction or based on the value obtained from the DB for a particular user I want to make some changes in the Theme of that particular page : PS :- The portlet and theme are in one particular page.